# How to update an XML file that uses MAP in Java

Tags: java

I have an XML file call it (xyz.xml) with sample data see below:

I want to read from the file(xyz.xml) and update the values in the same xml file.

Note(I have Variables that will contain data to be used in updating the xml file)

Brief description of my scenario[ I will read values from a different XML file first
and store them in a variables. Then I will use the variables to update the second xml file which is (xyz.zml)

How do I accomplish this in Java (Writing to the XML file(xyz.xml)) even if using a different approach?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<map xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/xpath-functions">
   <string key="ankomstDato">2019-06-03T09:24:40.486</string>
   <boolean key="samletUsrHoey">true</boolean>
   <array key="driftsform">
      <string>string_value</string>
   </array>
   <number key="versjon">0</number>
</map>
```

My sample java code , but I get

*Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at no.difi.oauth2.utils.SolutionXML2XmlFormat.Write2XMLfile(SolutionXML2XmlFormat.java:68)*

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;
import javax.xml.parsers.ParserConfigurationException;
import javax.xml.transform.Transformer;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerException;
import javax.xml.transform.TransformerFactory;
import javax.xml.transform.dom.DOMSource;
import javax.xml.transform.stream.StreamResult;
import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Element;
import org.w3c.dom.NamedNodeMap;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;
import org.w3c.dom.NodeList;
import org.xml.sax.SAXException;
//** */

public class SolutionXML2XmlFormat {
    //Create Public Variables to store data
    //**
    public static String ankomstDato_value;
    public static String art_value;
        
    //+++

    public void Xml2JavaObject(String TheXMLPath){
        //read the xml(TheXMLPath) and store values in variables

        //This is just an example
        ankomstDato_value = "2022-08-03T09:24:40.486";
                   
        //Call method to write values
        Write2XMLfile();
    }
    
    //Modify the existing values in Api_XML_Format.xml
    //*
    public void Write2XMLfile(){
        try {
            String filepath = "src/main/java/no/difi/oauth2/utils/Api_XML_Format.xml";
            DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
            DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
    
            // Get the root element , this case its "map"
            Node map = doc.getFirstChild();

            //1. ankomstDato
            Node ankomstDato = doc.getElementsByTagName("ankomstDato").item(0);
            ankomstDato.setTextContent(ankomstDato_value);
            //End ankomstDato
            
            //2. art
            //Node art = doc.getElementsByTagName("art").item(0);
            //art.setTextContent(art_value);
            //End art

            // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
            transformer.transform(source, result);
    
            System.out.println("Done Update The Api_XML_Format.xml");
    
           } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
            pce.printStackTrace();
           } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
            tfe.printStackTrace();
           } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
           } catch (SAXException sae) {
            sae.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please remember to include what your issue actually is..

However, I expect it's that you're running into a `NullPointerException` since `Node ankomstDato = doc.getElementsByTagName("ankomstDato").item(0);` wouldn't find anything and so it returns `null`.

The "tag name" it refers to is not actually what you seem to want to match; In this case the tag names are "string", "map", "boolean", "array", or "number". What you're trying to find is the node where it's attribute "key" has the value "ankomstDato".

I recommend using XPath instead to select the element you want. Here's an example to replace your `Write2XMLfile` method:

```
public void Write2XMLfile() {
    XPathFactory xpathFact = XPathFactory.newInstance();
    XPath xpath = xpathFact.newXPath();

    try {
        String filepath = "C:\\Users\\scsmi\\Desktop\\test.xml";
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

        // 1. ankomstDato
        Node ankomstDato = (Node) xpath.evaluate("(/map/string[@key='ankomstDato'])[1]", doc,
                XPathConstants.NODE);
        ankomstDato.setTextContent(ankomstDato_value );
        // End ankomstDato

        // 2. art
        // Node art = doc.getElementsByTagName("art").item(0);
        // art.setTextContent(art_value);
        // End art

        // 3. array
        NodeList arrayElements = (NodeList) xpath.evaluate("/map/array[@key='driftsform']/*", doc,
                XPathConstants.NODESET);
        for (int i = 0; i < arrayElements.getLength(); i++) {
            Node el = arrayElements.item(i);
            System.out.println("array element: tag='" + el.getNodeName() + "' text='"
                    + el.getTextContent() + "'");
        }
        // end array

        // write the content into xml file
        TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
        Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
        DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
        StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
        transformer.transform(source, result);

        System.out.println("Done Update The Api_XML_Format.xml");

    } catch (ParserConfigurationException pce) {
        pce.printStackTrace();
    } catch (TransformerException tfe) {
        tfe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException ioe) {
        ioe.printStackTrace();
    } catch (SAXException sae) {
        sae.printStackTrace();
    } catch (XPathExpressionException xee) {
        xee.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Question,1. Where do I pass value to that node 2. How do I deal with arrays . thanks

Comment: Read up a little on XPath syntax, particularly that which is supported by the XPath processor you're using. [Here's a good example](https://howtodoinjava.com/xml/java-xpath-tutorial-example/)

Comment: @KevinMbugua OK, I've updated to help you out a bit more

Comment: Thank you, This is actually greattttt, I got it. thank you again.

Comment: @KevinMbugua I'm glad, please accept this as the answer if it helped you. :)

Answer (score -1):

Change your code to :

```
//1. ankomstDato
if(doc.getElementsByTagName("ankomstDato") != null){
     Node ankomstDato = doc.getElementsByTagName("ankomstDato").item(0);
     ankomstDato.setTextContent(ankomstDato_value);
}
//End ankomstDato
```

Do this for each and every element of the doc while mapping of that data.

Comment: Am getting "The Method size() is undefined for the type Nodelist" .Secondly , will I handle arrays the same way.

Comment: please check now

Comment: I tried that and got Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: This approach in general is incorrect, read the documentation of `getElementsByTagName`